# How can a server know which DNS resolver was used to resolve its name?

Tags: domain-name-system

**Update**: The original question was made with wrong context in mind. What I should have really asked is how DNSBL works and why my DNS resolver matters.

I got the question examining this [explanational page](https://www.spamhaus.com/resource-center/successfully-accessing-spamhauss-free-block-lists-using-a-public-dns/) from Spamhaus. In particular it reads:

> public recursive name servers act as an anonymizing service and enable large-scale users to hide behind them

My current undesrtanding (backed with [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_recursive_name_server), [2](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/dns-resolver.htm), [3](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/know-how/dns-resolver/)) is that DNS resolver just converts a domain name to an IP address. Then I use the IP address to connect to the server. But in this case the server would be unaware what DNS I used.

So how can a DNS resolver be anonmizing or deanonimizing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you slightly miss the point as to what Spamhaus alludes to:

Spamhaus provides their blocklists via the [Domain Name System BlockList](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_blocklist) (DNSBL) mechanism.

To determine if a domain name or IP-address is listed  on the Spamhaus blocklist your system makes DNS query. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_blocklist#DNSBL_queries

When that domain name or IP-address is NOT listed the DNS Response Code NXDOMAIN is returned and another response, usually an IP-address from the 127.0.0.x range indicates a reason why that domain is listed.

Since Spamhaus needs to pay for their infrastructure they, like others have a freemium model. For small users the service is free, large users need to pay. They more or less implement that by counting the number of DNS queries from each IP-address. Each IP is allowed X number of "free" queries per day, when you exceed that number, please pay for the privilege.

When your system is configured to use Google's public resolvers, 8.8.8.8, your system won't query Spamhaus DNS servers directly. Your system will send the DNSBL query to 8.8.8.8 and when that particular query does not exist in that servers DNS cache, the Spamhaus DNS server will be queried on  your behalf by Google's public resolver.

That query does not come your IP-address , but uses the IP-address of Google's public resolver. (**edit:** That is also the *anonymizing* effect Spamhaus refers to. Your IP-address is hidden behind the Google public resolver.)

As you can imagine, there are many people using Google's public resolver and the free tier, the number of daily queries that a particular IP-address is allowed to make to Spamhaus, is quickly exhausted.

(And you can replace 8.8.8.8 with the IP-address of a large ISP and/or CloudFlare's secure DNS 1.1.1.1)

When you run your own DNS resolver, rather than your ISP's or 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1 etc. the DNSBL server will see your own IP-address as the origin of the DNS queries and if you're a small to medium business you won't run into any limits or rate limiting

Comment: Brilliant explanation!

Answer (score 0):

It is not "A DNS SERVER", it is "a PUBLIC and RECURSIVE name server". It means that I can hide the real name servers behind a public recursive server, hiding part of my ip infrastructure.

Comment: I'm apparently not aware of some important principle of domain name system so I just don't understand. Don't I first request an IP from it and then connect to the IP? So what is the role of the DNS when I already know server's IP?

Comment: It is hiding where your real name servers are. Normal name servers answer ony to domains they know, hence the hierarchy - you ask "." for the name server of .com etc. Recursive name servers forward the query for stuff they are not authoritative for.
Btw., any AI can provide an in depth explanation of that in seconds and you can discuss it there ;)

Comment: Thank you. My mistake was that I thought I query Spamhaus API, when actually I query my DNS for specially formed domain name and the request somehow lands on Spamhaus DNS. And in case I'm using e.g. Google DNS they see request from Google, not from me.